# Javascript array shows [object object] instead of showing the text

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, toastr

have been trying to pass a PHP array to a JavaScript array, but when I read out the content of that JavaScript array it shows literally [object, object].

```
if($error!='') {
    $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(json_encode(array(
            'message' => array(
                array(
                    'status'=>'error',
                    'message'=> $error1
                ),
                array(
                    'status'=>'error',
                    'message'=> $error2
                )
            )
        )));
}

$error1='Size Title Required !';
$error2='Size Code Required !';
```

I have been trying to pass a PHP array to a JavaScript array, but when I read out the content of that JavaScript array it shows literally [object, object].

Comment: What I think is happening is that your nested arrays are not being serialized to to JSON.

Comment: The default conversion from an object to string is "[object Object]" try accessing it array[0]

Comment: i'm new at this, can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: simply write array[0] then check..its php code I don't know how to access it

Answer (score 0):

do this to php array

```
var js_obj = <?php echo json_encode($phpArray); ?>)
 console.log(js_obj); // to check in console
```

and use it in javascript then

Answer (score -1):

That's because you have an JSON object. Use `JSON.Stringify(YourObject)`

Comment: i'm new at this, can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: show your JavaScript first where you are trying to access the variables.

Comment: $.ajax( {
    url: "<?php echo base_url("sizecodeuploaded"); ?>",
    type  : "POST", 
    dataType : "JSON", 
    data  : data,  
    processData : false, 
    contentType : false, 
    cache  : false, 
    async  : false, 
    success: function (data) {  
     if(data.status=='error'){
      $.toast({
       heading: 'Error',
       text: data.message,
       position: 'bottom-right',
       loaderBg:'#ff6849',
       icon: 'error',
       hideAfter: 3000
        });
     }
    },

Answer (score -1):

try using json_encode() method in PHP before passing to javascript.

And Use JSON.parse() method in JavaScript to fetch

Comment: i'm new at this, can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: var response = <?php print_r(json_encode($array)) ?>; response = JSON.Parse(response);